# Setting different font properties for certain characters in iOS TextKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, textkit

How would I go about setting different font properties for the degree symbol in this string?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaDu6.png

I am currently setting the value like this:

```
currentTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d°", [result[@"main"][@"temp"] intValue]];
```

And setting my font this way:

```
currentTemp.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:80];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `NSAttributedString` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This is exactly what you need.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *temp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"20 C"];
[temp addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[temp addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(3, 1)];
```

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete. Did you forget the `°` sign?

Comment: Really? :) I'm providing a way to learn and experience new things, not the copy-paste answer to simple task.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but some people may learn better by modifying a working example than by trying to make an incomplete example work. In this case, it seems weird that the answer is so close to solving the problem, and is just off by a couple of characters. Weird enough that I thought you had made a typo.

Comment: Any reason why systemFontofSize works but when I try to do [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:80] it fails

Comment: How does it fail exactly? Should not be any difference

Comment: `  NSMutableAttributedString *temp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d°", [result[@"main"][@"temp"] intValue]]];
        [temp addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                     value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:40.0]
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
        [temp addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                     value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:90.0]
                     range:NSMakeRange(3, 0)];
        
        currentTemp.attributedText = temp;`

Comment: That gives me weird results. My main text still looks larger and the other symbol is not reacting to font size 90

Comment: Second range should be 2,1 not 3,0 I think. Range with length 0 means you're not doing anything. Range is empty.

Comment: Great. I'm dumb. How can I adjust placement for the character?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. You would need to split the text into different pieces if you need that level of control.